# Different throughput per functionality in JMeter testplan

Tags: performance, jmeter

I am using JMeter to loadtest a webapplication.
We are using realistic throughput values based on Google Analytics. Each functionality has to deal with a different throughput level (eg. some pages are visited more than others)

Right now I do a test per functionality, one after the other. Which is not ideal. I'm using the Throughput Shaping Timer plugin to control the amount of requests per minute.

How in JMeter can I set different levels of throughput for different transaction controllers in one test?
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter timers have their scope. Basically if you put a timer on the same level with all requests - it will impact all of them, if you put the timer as a child of the certain request - it will affect only this particular request.

So it is possible to shape requests throughput individually. Even more, you can change throughput during test run if you'll use a JMeter Property as a throughput value and control it via [Beanshell server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server) Check out [How to use JMeter's Throughput Constant Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) guide for more details.

Comment: thanks for your answer and sorry for my late response.

I have used the constant throughput timer before, also as child of certain requests.
The problem: lets say the first request needs a throughput of 60RPM and the second 30 RPM. And I set Loop Count: forever. The first request wil receive the correct amount of throuhput the first time, and so will the 2nd request. But on the second loop there won't be enough threads to run the first request as they are still queuing for the 2nd request which passes threads at half speed

Comment: Are your requests dependent on each other? Can you separate out your requests into different thread groups?